# Particular form of bind temporary to const reference has no effect

Tags: c++, temporary, const-reference

Given

```
struct A
{
    void a(void) { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};

const A &a = A(); /* Make a copy of A and bind to a */
const A &b(A());  /* Does nothing */

a.a(); /* Prints A */
b.a(); /* Error, same as if b doesn't exist */
```

Why does the second form of "bind temporary to const reference" seem to be equivalent to a no-op?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just another case of [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), you're declaring a function rather than a const reference to `A`.

You could fix this by using C++11 uniform initialization:

```
const A &b{A()};
```

Comment: Is there no requirement for a diagnostic message in the standard? Seems like it would be helpful.

Comment: @DOS according to the wikipedia article, clang issues a warning. I don't know if there's anything in the standard about it.

Comment: @DOS VS2012 also issues a warning

Comment: That's probably why. I'm still using VS2010, although I'm surprised that GCC 4 doesn't say anything.